# Could not find compatible versions for gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, spree

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_auth":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_social (>= 0) ruby depends on
      spree_auth (~> 1.1.0) ruby

```
spree (= 0.50.2) ruby depends on
  spree_auth (0.50.2)
```

I was trying to integrate the spree social with my spree which is 0.50.x I got the following error. Please help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
gem install spree_social
```

and add into `Gemfile`

```
gem spree_social
```

and

```
bundle
```